# Determine current Tor exitNode using PHP

Tags: php, exit, tor

Hi
I wrote a PHP script that connects to some urls via TOR & Privoxy with CURL.
My script needs to change Tor Identity periodically. and needs that new identity be really new and didn't used before so I need to know what is current Tor Exit Node .
I need a technique to know what is my current tor exitNode via PHP script.

How Can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a website that tells you the IP you are connecting from. There are several such sites on the internet(TM).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. It is not possible from Tor Control Protocol?